# Interlocked average (CAS) not working on HLSL

Tags: concurrency, gpgpu, atomic, hlsl, interlocked

Hy everyone. I tried to implement an interlocked moving average, using InterlockedCompareExchange, on HLSL, but I got the GPU stuck on an infinite loop.

So, the code is this:

```
[allow_uav_condition] while (true)
{
    // Get old value
    uint old = irradianceVolume[vpos];

    // Average
    float3 avg = saturate((UnpackR5G5B5A1(old) + irradiance) * 0.5f);
    uint final = PackR5G5B5A1(float4(avg, 1));

    // Try to store
    uint ret = -1;
    InterlockedCompareExchange(irradianceVolume[vpos], old, final, ret);

    if (ret == old)
        break;
}
```

Here is the reference for the *InterlockedCompareExchange* function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471409(v=vs.85).aspx

If anyone can help with this, it would be really helpful. I'm hacking my way trough with a InterlockedMax for now, but that's hacky as hell, as you can sure imagine. It works quite good though.

Comment: Any comment? I'm still fighting with this problem

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the compiler doesn't realize that "uint old = irradianceVolume[vpos];" is essentially reading from shared memory. It may be 
1) pulling it out of the loop entirely
2) reading it from a stale cacheline, because atomics may not be coherent with reads that aren't done atomically.

If you replace it with "uint old; InterlockedAdd(irradianceVolume[vpos], 0,